# Change Numbers in Variable Range to Negative

Tags: excel, vba

I want to have a column in my worksheet changed to negative numbers as this column represents "stock out".

I got code from the below link which will change the values of a given range to negative:

https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/677-excel-change-positive-numbers-to-negative.html

But the problem is that this will require a user's interaction.

**Code:**

```
Sub ChangeToNegative()
    'Updateby20131113
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim WorkRng As Range

    On Error Resume Next

    xTitleId = "KutoolsforExcel"
    Set WorkRng = Application.Selection
    Set WorkRng = Application.InputBox("Range", xTitleId, WorkRng.Address, Type:=8)
    Set WorkRng = WorkRng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, xlNumbers)

    For Each rng In WorkRng
        xValue = rng.Value
        If xValue > 0 Then
            rng.Value = xValue * -1
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

I then found out to put the code in the worksheet itself and name the sub `Change(ByVal Target As Range)` which will update the selected range as you use it.

**Code:**

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim WorkRng As Range
    On Error Resume Next

    Set WorkRng = Application.Selection
    Set WorkRng = WorkRng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, xlNumbers)

    If Target.Address = WorkRng Then     
        For Each rng In WorkRng
            xValue = rng.Value
            If xValue > 0 Then
                rng.Value = xValue * -1
            End If
        Next 
    End If
End Sub
```

This works great, but it then means that whichever cell I click on and type in numbers, it will be a negative.

So instead of using `Application.Selection`, I want to give it a specific range - but one that could change.

1. So only if there is text in the cells `C5:C143`, then the cells `F5:F143` should be negative numbers
2. If I delete any cells between the `C5:C143`, then the range should be updated accordingly.

Perhaps the range could be based on text in `C4` and `C144` - so anything between these two text cells in column `F` would be a negative number?

Comment: You have to check if ye cell you are editing is in the desired range as first step in your worksheet change event

Comment: Not sure how your code works - `Target.Address` is a string while `WorkRng` is a range. `WorkRng` will reference all cells containing a numeric, while `Target.Address` will be the address of whichever cell in the selection you changed.

Answer (score 1):

I've added plenty of comments to explain what the code does.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim WorkRng As Range
    Dim RangeToCheck As Range
    Dim rCell As Range

    'Don't Resume Next - if an error occurs handle it properly
    'and don't just hope the code can carry on regardless.
    On Error GoTo Err_Handle

    'This is the range we're looking at.
    'Use a named range so the range will update if you add/remove cells.
    Set RangeToCheck = Union(Range("Column_C_Figures"), Range("F5:F143"))

    'Are any cells within the required range?
    If Not Intersect(Target, RangeToCheck) Is Nothing Then

        'The cell will be updated, so disable events so
        'Worksheet_Change doesn't fire a second time.
        Application.EnableEvents = False

        'Look at each cell in Target.
        'More than one cell could change if values pasted in, or row deleted, or....
        For Each rCell In Target
            'All values in Target may not be in RangeToCheck so only look at
            'the ones that are.
            If Not Intersect(rCell, RangeToCheck) Is Nothing Then
                If IsNumeric(rCell) And rCell > 0 Then
                    rCell = rCell * -1
                End If
            End If
        Next rCell

    End If

Fast_Exit:

    Application.EnableEvents = True

Exit Sub

Err_Handle:
    'Deal with any errors and resume so that events are re-enabled.
    Select Case Err.Number
        'Case 13 'Example of error that may occur.
            'Deal with a data type mismatch and either
            'Resume, Resume Next or Resume Fast_Exit.
        Case Else
            Resume Fast_Exit
    End Select

End Sub
```